# ¿Cómo evito operar sobre una matriz con columnas o filas vacías?

Tags: prolog

En el problema que intento resolver una matriz bien definida no tiene filas ni columnas vacías.

Por ejemplo la matriz `[[],[]]` no es válida.

Cuando llamo a la función `first_column`, ¿cómo evito que se ejecute si la matriz que envío como argumento no está definida correctamente como he dicho anteriormente?

```
first_column([],[],[]).

first_column([[H|T]|Tail],[H|Col],[T|Rows]):-

    first_column(Tail,Col,Rows).
```